# SBT Stuck Downloading Artifacts

Tags: scala, sbt

So, I just want to compile my project. sbt starts downloading artifacts. I lose connection, some of the artifacts are half downloaded. Later I try to continue, download of these artifacts gets stuck. I retry the build - stuck (at the same percentage). I delete ~/.ivy2, retry - stuck. I delete ~/.sbt AND ~/.ivy2 and retry - stuck.

It (sbt) seems to think that the files are partially downloaded when they're not and it's trying to continue the download and it can't because the parts of the files are not there. So it appears to be stuck in some illegal state, but whatever I do, I cannot seem to nudge it out of it. Is there any sort of "master reset" (other than reinstalling my OS) of this situation?

[image]

[Download progress of ghost artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh46I.png)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by adding

```
externalResolvers := Seq("Repo" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/")
```

to my build.sbt. This forced download from the alternative public repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting your build to a clean state

```
sbt clean
```

and then (optionally) removing `~/.ivy2` cache. (You might also remove everything inside target directories: `target`, `project/target`).

If issue persist, try checking if you are able to download the artifact yourself via e.g. `curl`.

Comment: AFAIR this only works assuming you know that to put into your `.gitignore` (which you might not know if you don't know about `target`)

Comment: Hi Mateusz, thanks for your answer! I did try this first. After this, I removed ~/.ivy2 directory. To no avail. At this point it's not about wasting time any more. I'm just not able to build anything that includes these 4 libraries, because when it comes to downloading them... well... you've seen the picture

Also, this doesn't have to do anything with git, the project is not a git repo.